# 800A01C2 - Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

I tried to search for the issue I have but couldn't find any online. 
Her is what I want to do: When I run the test.vbs file, I take a user input then pass it to a batch file.

I got this error:

> 800A01C2 - Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment

at line 4 in VBScript code.

Here is my test.vbs code:

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
strInput = InputBox("Please enter the date (yyyymmdd)", "Enter Date")
set strInput = WScript.Arguments
WshShell.Run "mybatch.bat" & strInput, 0
```

Just a simple code to output the parameter that passed from vbs to batch file:

```
echo Parameter = %1 > Var.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

`WScript.Arguments` is an object, and so is `strInput` (by assignment). The string concatenation operator `&` can concatenate strings (and stringified whatevers), but not objects. Evidence:

```
>> a = "a " & WScript.Arguments
>>
Error Number:       450
Error Description:  Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment
```

So

```
WshShell.Run "mybatch.bat" & strInput, 0
```

must fail. So delete the assignment and use the string obtained from the `InputBox()` function, or access an item from the `Arguments` collection (without `Set`).

In any case make sure there is a blank/space between "mybatch.bat" and the parameter.